# Why is Unity not loading properly?

Tags: unity, 12.10, compiz, screen, display-resolution

I wanted to try out League of Legends. I installed PlayOnLinux and got *LoL* working through it, but whenever I ran the game it changed my screen resolution to something a bit smaller than my screeen, I changed this back by pressing 'Fn + F7' which has a screen change icon on my laptop on F7.

I don't know what's happened now, but whenever I turn my laptop off and on again, it loads with a black screen. I have to press 'Fn + F7' every time, and then I just get my desktop loaded but nothing else, no bar at the top, not menu at the side, Ctrl + Alt + T works though and that is how I have been managing to get some things to work.
I have tried reinstalling compiz and unity (said "package not found", so I installed it, but don't really know what it did; nothing changed).

So at the moment, I used Terminal to run 'startx' as root and then run compiz and unity and it is almost normal again but I'm **logged in as root**, not as me..
So my background is different, my docs aren't there etc.

How can I make it back to normal? I don't really have time to reinstall Ubuntu at the moment, and want to get back to 12.04 or 11.10 as 12.10 seems a bit unfinished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset your unity configuration. Type in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:amith/ubuntutools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-reset
```

Logged in as your user, type `unity-reset`

Source: [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html)